# how can I convert a std::map with multiple indexes to boost::multi_index_container

Tags: c++, boost, random-access, boost-multi-index

I need some guidance to get some the following [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d49592c1459b7df3) that I put together on Coliru working to use a `boost::multi_index_container`. The live example has 2 sections, a simple slightly modified example of the `boost::multi_index_container` showing at least that I can get a Boost live example working on coliru — it also has a very simplified pair of indices specified. Secondly I have class that I am trying to adapt to use a `multi_index_container`. The `IndexContainer` essentially at its core contains a `std::map` of `std::map`s per the following typedefs in the class

```
typedef enum  { INSYNC, UPDATE, LOAD, EXTRA } FileType;
// 4 separate types of indeces defined 
typedef std::tuple<int32_t, int32_t, int32_t, int32_t> IndexQuartet;

// typedef showing relationship between IndexQuartet & its LoadableFiles
typedef std::map<IndexQuartet, std::set<LoadableFile>> IndexedFileInfo;

// define a mapping between the file type and its indexed files
typedef std::map<FileType, IndexedFileInfo> FileInfo;
```

The `IndexContainer` class has `updateFileInfo` and `getFileInfo` methods to modify the underlying `FileInfo` map of maps containers.  The interesting structure `IndexQuartet` contains 4 separate indexes and I would like to be able to independently iterate through the `LoadableFile`s using one of the 4 indices specified in the aforementioned `IndexQuartet` but I am not really sure how to go about changing the simple `std::set` based employee like example shown at the start to do something based on a combination of `std::map`s and tuples.

Any help or guidance as to how I could do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Actually I think the question was pretty specific, I even coded up and included a live working corilu demo.  The place I am stuck is understanding how to correctly migrate the std::map<FileType, IndexedFileInfo> into equivalent boost indexes, I did read the documentation but it seems rather vague in that area, its very speific when it comes to sets though.

Comment: Well well. I just spent 10 minutes to figure out that you basically just crammed some unrelated **[`employee` sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ddbd39267611e86)** right into **[your existing code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f374b1a7da4a396)**. I have a hard time coming up with reasons ***not*** to see this a "Write my code for me" type request. (Kudos for the SSCCE, though).

Comment: The second sentence of my question says "The live example has 2 sections".  I do generally try to include a live working SSCCE as it does make it easier for others, also I included plenty of comments.  Perhaps I should have put more of the comments in the question instead :)

Comment: Okay. FWIW: here's the SSCCE without some of the noise: [67 instead of 179 lines of code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b80b55b6027f9a8) (not even counting the multi-index sample code). I'm still not sure what you expect to happen. What does _"I would like to be able to independently iterate through the LoadableFiles using one of the 4 indexes"_ mean? Do you expect to keep the map of maps? Why not? Would you still require the same uniqueness guarantees? Is this actually more like a database table (i.e. flat with unique constraints)?

Comment: I suggest you break your text into paragraphs for clarity. I tried to, but couldn’t figure it out.